# Why is the data displayed using D3.js looks cutoff?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js

I am using D3.js to draw some circles inside a div but for some reason no data is displayed in the bottom third of the did even though the specified size of the canvas is equivalent to the size of the of the div.

```
var data = d3.csv('circles.csv', function(data){
    var canvas = d3.select('.cell').append("svg");

    canvas.selectAll("circles")
            .attr("width", 300)
            .attr("height", 250)
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("cx", function(d){return (+d.x)})
            .attr("cy", function(d){return (+d.y)})
            .attr("r", function(d){return (+d.radius)})
            .attr("fill", "green");
});
```

Comment: Create an [mcve], Luke - welcome to stackoverflow

Comment: @user2464 Did you specify the svg size(I did not see it in ur code)? I remember there is a 300 by 150 default viewport size for SVG if u did not set the SVG size(my understanding is viewport decide how big area u can see the elements inside ) so 150/250 = 3/5, which means the bottom 2/5 can not be displayed

Answer (score 0):

I set a code snippet for what it looks like if no svg size specified. So if ur case is like this, the data point at the bottom may be just go out the SVG viewport area.

```js
var canvas = d3.select('.cell').append("svg")
                // if u did not specify size
                //.attr("width", 400).attr("height", 400);

canvas.selectAll("circle").data([0])
//  .attr("width", 300)
//  .attr("height", 250)
//  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return 150;
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return 125;
  })
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return 125;
  })
  .style("fill", "green");
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="cell" style="width:500px; height:500px;"></div>

</body>

</html>
```